# Spring Rest API and Angular, block outside specific domain

Tags: spring, angular, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a website (let's call it a web service) with Spring REST backend and Angular Frontend. It's a website, Spring REST is used to get data from daефbase via Sring Data JPA.

I am totally new to client side rendering, every other servicies I was build with server-side rendering architecture, where I used JSP for servering pages.

So I have a question, how do I secure my API? Let's say my site domain is `21example.com`, and in angualr I am calling to `back-end-server/api/posts/latest` to get latest posts in json and render them in frontend using angular (just for example, it's actually not just posts.).

**And here goes my question**: How to prevent someone else to just opening my angular .js files and seeing the API url and then just stealing all my data by using the same API calls (I know the data is public, but still, it's like giving someone else keys from your house) or in the worst case jsut using my back-end to server data to his frontend.. Am I understanding it right - I can't block by IP, because all API calls are made on client site, so frontend server IP doesn't matter here?

Only way to secure an API i've found is using Spring Security, but I don't need authorization, because my service is public. I came to a theory that I can block request if they are made outside my domain `21example.com` Is it how it works? I can't use IP-specific blocks in `RestController`, because it's a publciu web serivice. Is it how it works?

Comment: Whether you expose a JSON API or HTML pages doesn't change anything. It's only marginally harder to scrape server-generated HTML than to scrape server-generated JSON. Browsers won't let a web app make cross-origin AJAX requests unless you explicitly enable CORS. But any other client can of course get your data if it's public.

Comment: But is using server-side rendering still considers good? I've read many topic on IT resources, which say that client-side rendering is the future.. but idk. for me it was way easier just to use jsp

Comment: But what will happend if I will define apiUrl as private? Will it somehow hide the url from client?

Comment: You didn't read me carefully. Whether you expose data publicly as HTML (using JSPs) or using JSON doesn't change anything: if the data is exposed publicly, it's available to anyone. Whether you use JSPs or not thus doesn't change anything. If you don't want people to access your data, don't make it public. If you make it public, in HTML or in JSON, people can get it.